# Как складывать в теле цикла?

Tags: javascript

> По данному натуральному N вычислите сумму 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2. Результат выведите в мини-браузер. Например, при N = 128 ответ: 707264. Значение N менять нельзя. Решать можно только при помощи цикла for!

Не могу понять, как в теле цикла складывать сумму квадратов.

```
var N = 128;
var c = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 128 ; i++) {
    c = i*i;
}
document.write(c);
```

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи.** Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: `c = i*i;` - это почему?

Comment: Квадрат числа ищу, не могу понять как сумму квадратов найти

Comment: тогда уж `c += i*i;`  и `i <= 128` "Все, Груздева надо выпускать!"

Comment: 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2
Не так написал условие задачи

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы, очевидно, забыли произвести само сложение:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 128; i++) { // по условию, цикл должен идти пока "меньше или равно"
    c = c + i*i; 
    // то же можно записать как c += i*i;
}
```